# Is there a way to implement Cybersource as an Iframe in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway, iframe, cybersource

***I have a Magento 1, and we are using the official Magento 1 Cybersource extension***

```
https://marketplace.magento.com/cybersource-cybersource-cybersource.html
```

*We have set it up and successfully activated web/mobile (which redirects to an external form).*

*Because we are PCI compliant, we need this to be SAQ-A. The external form is actually SAQ-A. However, the business wants us to implement the payment in an iframe.*

> I was digging into the Cybersource documentation and googling a lot,
>   but I was not able to find an implementation of Cybersource with
>   iframes.

***Does anyone know anything about it?***

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use other method  like "Silent Order Processing" or SOAP instead Web/Mobile. For Web/Mobile you will redirect to Cybersource page for payment.

Comment: @PritamInfo24 I don't really know what do you mean with your answer. I have already established in my post that Web/Mobile redirects to an external form. I also mentioned that it covers the security need of being SAQ-A. 

I will ask the question again. Do you know a way to implement iframes with Cybersource? Please, if you don't know how to do it, do not answer, as it will not help me and will waste both our time. Yours by answering something that is not useful in this context, and mine because I will actually have to read it.

Thanks for understanding.